# Замена символа по коду

Tags: php, кодировка, notepad++, символы

Поступил мне заказ. Как мне описали ТЗ:

1. Есть файл, в котором несколько статей,
2. Каждая строка разделена тремя или более Enter-ами,
3. Статья состоит из заголовка, первой строки, и текста,
4. Все остальные строки, где абзацев меньше трех...

и т. д.

Написал скрипт в Notepad++. Для разбивки и определения абзацев использовал символ `\n`.

Пример (этот код разбивал мой текст на элементы массива, разделены тремя абзацами):

```
$arraytext= explode("\n\n\n", $contents);
```

Когда заказчик начал проверять, оказалось, что у него вручную файл не разбивает. А копирует текст из редактора — в каждой строке видны непонятные пробелы. Я их скопировал и пропустил через скрипт для вывода кода символов:

```
$i=0;
$lines = file('111.txt');
foreach($lines as $single_line){
    echo ord($single_line[0]).'<br>';
}
```

В итоге получил вот такой список кодов:

> 10
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   10
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32
>   32

Каким я вижу решение проблемы: заменить все символы с кодами 10 и 32 на `\n`, потом удалить лишние `\n` и мой скрипт будет работать с контентом.

**Проблема**: какой код у символа перевода строки `\n`, и как найти и заменить коды 10 и 32? Насколько я понимаю функция `str_replace` здесь не сработает.

Если есть другие возможности решения моей проблемы, буду рад узнать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте разбивать так:

```
preg_split("/(?:\\n[ \\r]*){3,}/, $arr);
```

Разбивает независимо от наличия пробелов и независимо от количества переводов строк.

Comment: ну опечатку в расчет брать не будем, а так все работает!!! 

Супер!

не подскажете, где можно почитать об регулярках, чтобы было более мение понятно... я бы такую конструкцию никогда не составил (((

Comment: Дж. Фридл Регулярные выражения